# div занимает больше места, чем нужно

Tags: html, css

имеем небольшой код:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/tree/tree_PNG2517.png" width="30%"> 
</div>
<style>
    div{
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы div занимал площадь == площади картинки ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

width="30%" - это ширина от родительского элемента
Попробуйте поставить DIV-у свойство width:30%, а изображению width:100%
Либо для картинки укажите точную ширину.

Также в CSS есть свойства с привязкой к размерам экрана
например
vw  Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp